# How do I tile MDI children and maintain BorderStyle = bsNone?

Tags: delphi, mdi, mdichild

I am hoping someone can help

I have created an object that has a form. I instantiate this object during runtime. The user can then instantiate a second (or multiple) object(s) via a menu step. So two child forms now exist in a parent form. Each objects form's BorderStyle is set to none and Style is set to MDIChild during form creation at runtime:

```
BorderStyle := bsNone;
FormStyle := fsMDIChild;
```

All fine. Form has no border.

Now I want to tile the two forms created. Menu > click Tile

```
procedure TMainForm.Tile1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     Tile;
end;
```

Now the border re-appears. **I need a way to get rid of the border.**

I have tried stepping through the collection of objects and explicitly setting the BorderStyle to none:

```
procedure TMainForm.Tile1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i: byte;
begin
    Tile;
    for i := 0 to GraphCollection.Count-1 do
        (GraphCollection.Items[i] as TGraphForm).BorderStyle := bsNone;
end;
```

This does not work.

Does anyone have a workaround that retains the bsNone style after either Tile or Cascade.

Comment: [The documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.BorderStyle) says changing `BorderStyle` to `bsNone` has no effect on MDI children. Perhaps that's what you're seeing here. Several search results mention overriding `CreateParams`; have you tried that?

Comment: What's "graphcollection"? Shouldn't the code in "Tile1Click" be  'for i:= 0 to MDIChildCount - 1 do if MDIChildren[i] is TGraphForm then TGraphForm (MDIChildren[i]).BorderStyle:= bsNone;' ?

Comment: MDI is quite restrictive in what you can do. Expect this to be impossible. Find a way to do this without mdi.

Comment: Rob. Thanks for the comments. The border style changed from bsNone to bsSizeable when I tile. I want to retain a bsNone style after tilling. I have tried the CreateParams option. No joy.

Comment: No'am. Graphcollection is a TObjectList of Forms created. I had tried both options (as per my post and similar to as suggested by you). No joy

Comment: Thanks David. Looks like this is not possible. Any code for the tilling look without using MDI???

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in another way. I do this with Tabset (TTabSet class) without using fsMDIChild(but BorderStyle = bsNone).

You can add a tab for each form you open on TabSet. By clicking any tab, you can activate or show appropriate form. And delete the appropriate tab for any form by closing it. I prepare an example and you can get it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fd9ytdp2scwglns/MDIForms%20tabset-Sample.zip?dl=0).

(I miss-understand the question, my answer is about simulating MDITab for MdiChild forms when the FormStyle is fsNormal and not fsMdiChild)

Comment: How would you simulate the tile effect?

Comment: I added a description to my answer.